# Windows server 2008 r2 sharepoint server

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to set up Windows Server 2008 r2 to programm sharepoint online, as there seems no other option available. 
Are there any options I can do this without Windows Server 2008 r2? 
I've tried to set up Windows 7 to act like a sharepoint server, but it does not work: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44210/Installing-SharePoint-Server-2010-on-Windows-7-x64

Are there any options available that I don't need WS2008 R2?

Comment: It works for me. But also, see [sharepoint.se].

Comment: I did not know there was a special Sharepoint site for this. Thanks

Comment: What's the problem you run into? I'd recommend using a Windows Server 2008 R2 box for development. Create one on a virutal platform like Hyper-V or VM-ware. That's probably the most used scenario. Either that, or a beefy notebook with something like Virtual Box.